# How to apply a lambda with 2 parameters to a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I can take the following lambda expression:

```
\x y -> x * y
```

and apply it like:

```
(\x y -> x * y) 9 9
81

(\x y -> x * y) 8 8
64
```

If I want to express something like, "Take the above lambda, and map it over a list, each item being a pair of values, like above, and return a list, each value being the result of having applied that lambda expression", how can I do it?

In pseudo-code I mean something like: Take `(\x y -> x * y)` and apply it to something like `[(9, 9), (8, 8)]`.

I know that if I had `\x -> x + 1`, I can do the following:

```
map (\x -> x + 1) [9, 9, 9]
[10,10,10]
```

In other words, I'm trying to find out if it is possible (and how) to do something like

```
map (\x y -> x * y) [ a list of items, each being a pair of values, on which the lambda can work ]
```

Apparently, the following doesn't work:

```
map (\x y -> x * y) [(9, 9), (8, 8)]
```

it doesn't return `[81, 64]`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
let list = [(9, 9), (8, 8)]
-- if you want to do it inline
map (\(x, y) -> x * y) list
-- or if you already have a 2 parameter version of a function
let f x y = x * y 
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
map (uncurry f) list
```

There's a difference between `\(x, y) -> x * y :: (Int, Int) -> Int` and `\x y -> x * y :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

The first is a function that takes one parameter - a tuple and returns the result of multiplication.

The second is a function that takes two parameters and returns the result of multiplication.

Comment: Or, in other words `map (uncurry (\x y -> x * y)) [(9, 9), (8, 8)]` to get `[81, 64]`. Thanks! :)

Comment: That works, but you'd normally write it as `map (\(x, y) -> x * y) [(9, 9), (8, 8)]`.
Because `(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int` is also a binary function it's also possible to write it as `map (uncurry (*)) [(9, 9), (8, 8)]`, but I prefer the version above.